# Earliest opportunity to get @Context field in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, code-injection

I can make an object visible to my Jersey resources by making it a property of the `Application` (or `ResourceConfig`)

This doesn't work:

```
public class MyResource {
    @Context private Application app;
    private SomeType thing;

    public MyResource() {
         thing = (SomeType) app.getProperties().get("thing"); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

... because evidently the injection does not happen until after the constructor has run.

This does work:

```
public class MyResource {
    @Context private Application app;
    private SomeType thing;

    @GET
    @Path("foo")
    public AnotherType get() {
         thing = (SomeType) app.getProperties().get("thing"); // NullPointerException
         ...
    }
}
```

But it seems inelegant to have a step to get that property at the start of every method (even if it's a call to a lazy initialization method).

Is there some other way I can make a method run *after* the constructor but *before* any `@GET`/`@POST`/etc methods are called?

Comment: `@PostConstruct` is your friend. As long as your class is registered with Jersey, a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` will be called after the the class is instantiated and the injections are completed and before any service calls are executed.

Comment: @Baldy That works perfectly. Thanks. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. Could you also mention where I could have found this for myself - no mention of PostConstruct in the Jersey 2.8 User Guide https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PostConstruct` is your friend.

As long as your class is registered with Jersey, a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` will be called after the the class is instantiated and the injections are completed and before any service calls are executed.

This isn't called out specifically in the Jersey docs that I'm aware of but there are some mentions of it on Google. It does make sense since with any injection framework, injections need to occur after object creation and they all use the `@PostConstruct` annotation to provide a place to do initialization after injection is complete.